# Designated initializer should only invoke a designated initializer on 'super'

Tags: objective-c

This code is a modified version of Ordered Dictionary implemented here.
https://github.com/nicklockwood/OrderedDictionary/tree/master/OrderedDictionary

**Interface -> OrderedDictionary.h**

```
 @interface OrderedDictionary : NSMutableDictionary
{
}
```

**Implementation -> OrderedDictionary.m**

```
// This is the new method added.
- (instancetype)init
{
    return [self initWithCapacity:0];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)capacity
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
       // Allocate here.
    }
    return self;
}
```

The code works fine but I get following warnings in "- (instancetype)init".

1. Designated initializer should only invoke a designated initializer
   on 'super'
2. Designated initializer missing a 'super' call to a
   designated initializer of the super class

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

***Made following changes to the code to fix the problem***

```
 // This is the new method added.

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
       // Allocate here.
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)capacity
{
    self = [super initWithCapacity:capacity];
    if (self != nil)
    {
       // Allocate here.
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: While @KirkSpaziani's answer did the trick, the [iOS Develop Libraries Object Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW8) adds some detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in [NSMutableDictionary documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/index.html), there are two designated initializer for this class:

- `initWithCapacity:` Designated Initializer
- `init` Designated Initializer

Here you are calling from initWithCapacity in your class to super.init. That's the reason the compiler warns you.

This code maybe is better:

```objective-c
// This is the new method added.
- (instancetype)init
{
    return [self initWithCapacity:0];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)capacity
{
    self = [super initWithCapacity:capacity];
    if (self != nil)
    {
       // Allocate here.
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This did not fix the issue but thanks to this I understood what was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: If it didn't fix the issue, then you should not accept the answer as correct.

Answer (score 4):

try adding
    - (instancetype)initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)capacity NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

To the @interface block.  All initialization paths should flow through the designated initializer - in your case initWithCapacity: is the obvious choice since init calls it.  You may still run into problems, the designated initializer must call the super class's designated initializer.  If the super class defines designated initializers those must be implement by your class as well...

In general subclassing NSMutableDictionary is considered bad practice because NSMutableDictionary is the public facing piece of a class cluster.  This may be part of the cause of the compiler warnings.

Comment: This fixed the warnings I was facing but introduced a new one concerning "initWithCoder". It was good to know this option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet some of you are tripping over this warning message when you have Xcode convert your code to "Modern Objective-C Syntax."

I've seen cases where Objective-C header files have been modified by the converter to have two designated initializers:

```
- (instancetype) init NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;                                    // DO NOT USE
- (instancetype) initWithFileset: (NSArray *) fileset NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;    // use this to instantiate
```

If you modify this code to a single initializer, you may find the warning message goes away:

```
- (instancetype) init;                                                              // DO NOT USE
- (instancetype) initWithFileset: (NSArray *) fileset NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;    // use this to instantiate
```

In short, check the header and the source file when you see this warning message.

Answer (score -1):

You should only call the super of your own function.

So replace

```
self = [super init];
```

with

```
self = [super initWithCapacity:capacity];
```

Comment: This is not true - all initialization should go through your current class's designated initializer.